# Make table name unique for a user only and not across the entire database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have here, for example, a user with many groups and the database is structured as follows:

```rb
class CreateGroups < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :groups, id: :uuid do |t|
      t.uuid    :user_id
      t.string  :name

      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :groups, :name, unique: true
  end
end
```

The above will make `name` being unique across the entire database. I want `name` to be unique based on the user (`user_id`). Is that possible at database level? To have something like this, do I have to use [find or create](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/first_or_create) instead?

If I have two users, they should be able to create the same group names but should not be the same for each user:

```rb
User.first.groups.first.name #> Bold
User.first.groups.second.name #> Bold (should fail)

User.second.groups.first.name #> Bold (should be ok)
User.second.groups.second.name #> Bold (should fail)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its called a multicolumn index (aka composite index, combined index, or concatenated index) and you can create them by passing an array:

```
class CreateGroups < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :groups, id: :uuid do |t|
      t.uuid    :user_id
      t.string  :name
      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :groups, [:user_id, :name], unique: true
  end
end
```

On the application side you can validate this by using:

```
class Group < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, uniqueness: { scope: :user_id }
end
```

This provides user feedback and prevents a database driver error while the actual DB index [safeguards against race conditions](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/the-perils-of-uniqueness-validations).

Answer (score 2):

Just change

```
add_index :groups, :name, unique: true
```

to

```
add_index :groups, [:user_id, :name], unique: true
```